# Fan Direction MacBook

Tags: macbook-pro

I bought a cooler for the bottom of my MacBook because I use it on my bed.  The Instructions say to flip it so it doesn't work against the computer.  I don't want to open it up because it's loaned to me from my school.

All I would like to know is if the fans are pulling air in or pushing air out?

Apple MacBook Mid 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MacBook released in 2010 has intake and output on the back of the computer. There are no vents on the bottom.